# Why do I get this glass result?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, transparency, glass

Pretty strange that I get this glass result. I am making a a wine bottle so nothing too complicated. I think I will do my model again, but I would like to understand what makes the model being this unrealistic? I tried to play with a lot of settings, I followed advanced tutorials but even then nothing made sense. Here is the file yo ucan download : https://pasteall.org/blend/a9482823b5024548ae168368464bef96

[image]

Comment: Looks like bad geometry to me. Try to clean it up in the first place, by *removing any duplicated vertices* -> *Edit Mode > Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance* and make sure your normals are pointing in the right direction.

Comment: It helped a bit but not completely. It seems that my model is a complete mess with the normals. So I did it again. Thanks for the support !

Comment: That looks like overlapping faces, probably duplicated or so close together that they create z-fighting.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked !